# How do I make Sphinx autodoc document a function which is an attribute of an object?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a module where I create a function `chain` (acting kind of like [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)), so I thought I'd mimic the `itertools` interface and expose a `chain.from_iterable` function, too. To do that, I just define another function and then duct-tape it onto `chain` like this:

```
chain = _create_chain(environment)
```

and somewhere in `_create_chain`:

```
_chain.from_iterable = _from_iterable
return _chain
```

Both `chain` and `chain.from_iterable` have docstrings, and everything works fine, but I want to document both `chain` and `chain.from_iterable` automatically with Sphinx. Right now I have

```
.. automodule:: mymodule
   :members:

   .. autofunction:: chain
```

and it creates docs for `chain`, but adding another `autofunction` directive for `chain.from_iterable` results in an `ImportError` because it thinks `chain` is a module:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import function u'from_iterable' from module u'chain'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 335, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
ImportError: No module named chain
```

How do I include the docs for `chain.from_iterable` in this scenario?

Comment: @Delosari no, not really. I still have documentation for those functions inside the rst files, separate from the autodoc directive.